# Python object state tracking idiom

Tags: python, object, state, idioms

I have an object that acts as an interface to a remote system, and I need to keep track of various states.  Which is the better or more pythonic way of doing this?  would one way be preferable if the list of states gets really long or complicated?

A. with object attributes:

```
class Session (object):
    def__init__(self):
        self.a_set = False
        self.b_set = False

    def set_a(self):
        self.a_set = True
```

B. with a dict that represents the state:

```
    class Session (object):
    def__init__(self):
        self.state = {}

    def set_a(self):
        self.state['a_set'] = True
```

Additional Details:

I originally set up a state dict, so that I could do a quick reset:

```
def reset_state(self):
    for k in self.state:
        self.state[k] = False
```

I may end up with a bunch of sub-classes that will need to track additional states, but still reset them all at once.
I just want to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot, or doing anything really weird/anti-pattern.

Comment: Wouldn't a better 'quick reset' be just creating a new instance of the class and tossing the old one?

Comment: @polpak I may need to preserve *part* of the state.  so, I may have a hostname for the session, a note that I have installed something, but its rebooting so I have to disconnect and reconnect which wipes out session variables on the remote host that then need to be re-set.

Comment: Well in your self.state example then you could just re-initialize it with self.state = {} instead of assigning all the keys to False.

Comment: @polpak not true! `if state['x']: do_thing()` will return a keyError

Comment: Sure, but it's also the case that False could be valid data and different than the absence of data. It's hard to know what the correct solution is without knowing more about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user perspective, it should look like the first option; we should be able to use:

```
if session.a_set:
    do_something()
```

There are a couple different ways to implement that:

```
# simple method
class Session(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_set = False
        self.b_set = False
    def reset(self):
        self.b_set = False
```

However, if you have more than a couple hand-fulls of variables this would quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

I suggest the `class decorator` approach, with a couple helpers:

```
# not strictly necessary
class Persist(object):
    """
    Do not clear this variable with reset().
    """
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

# necessary
class Reset(object):
    """
    Clear this variable with reset().
    """
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

def BuildResets(cls):
    reset = cls.resetable = []
    persist = cls.persistent = []
    for name, obj in cls.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(obj, Reset):
            setattr(cls, name, obj.value)
            reset.append(name)
        elif isinstance(obj, Persist):
            setattr(cls, name, obj.value)
            persist.append(name)
    return cls
```

and in use:

```
@BuildResets
class Session(object):
    self.a_set = Persist(False)
    self.b_set = Reset(False)
    def reset(self):
        for name in self.resetable:
            setattr(self, name, False)
```